# Date is incorrectly showing as British Summer Time

Tags: javascript, date

I am currently in the UK.

I am obtaining a date from my api which is the following string value = `"2021-06-15T21:00:00Z"`.
But when I want to convert this to a Date object using:

```
let formattedStartDateTime: Date = new Date("2021-06-15T21:00:00Z");
```

I get the following result = `Tue Jun 15 2021 22:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time).`

Why am I getting British Summer Time? I'm running this today so I would expect it to be `GMT+0000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date you are storing and outputting are the same, you are just outputting your local date instead of the UTC date, this should do what you want.

```
let formattedStartDateTime: Date = new Date("2021-06-15T21:00:00Z");
console.log(formattedStartDateTime.toUTCString());
```